# NavigationBar with NO accent in the words

Tags: ios, utf-8, uinavigationbar

i'm Brazilian and we have many words with accents ( ` ~ ' )
I have a NavigationBar with the word "informações" but the ~ doesnt show up.
Other words doesnt show too.
How I can Fix that?

Comment: Post the code where you set `informações` as title, because it works when I code post `informações` in to my code and set it as the title. See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9pkx6ddhz1zbei/title.png

Comment: I just put `self.title = @"INFORMAÇÕES";`
If I put directly in the Right Side Panel also doest work

Comment: Your error i lies somewhere else, both small case and capital case works in my project. Are you using a custom font? Does that font support the `Õ` character?

Comment: Is not a custon font. Is DIN CONDENSED.
But the font is not the problem, because if a put this word in a Text Field, it works.

Comment: Well if I paste  `self.title = @"INFORMAÇÕES"` into my `viewDidLoad` it works. So the problem lies somewhere else in your code. So please share a bit more about you code that might be the problem.